# Are there any subversion "dash board" web applications that can show me a list of recent commits from all my repositories?

Tags: version-control, web-applications, svn

I am looking for something like a subversion dashboard that at the very least can show me commits from across a group of repositories. Is there anything like this available? Since it could just as well be dead simple and I can't find anything immediately I am thinking if just scratching my own itch here, but I am hoping someone has wanted this before? Are there any subversion "dashboards" that an show me even a simple twitter-like list of commits from across my repositories?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My shop was looking for something similar a few years ago, so we asked around and were told about [Beanstalk](http://beanstalkapp.com/), which has this functionality, and presents it in a river-of-news (Twitter) format for all repositories together:

[image: Beanstalk Dashboard]

Notably, it works for Git in addition to SVN.

If you're interested in going the open-source, self-hosted route, check out [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/milestone/0.12), which added multiple repository support in 0.12. Vitor Braga in the comments also mentioned [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) as a possible option, as well.

Comment: awesome! I didn't realize WebSVN would do this, will look into it -- thank you.

Comment: If I recall correctly Redmine can do this do too.

Comment: @Joe I just double-checked WebSVN, and I don't believe there's a way to show the river-of-news for multiple repositories at the same time, so I removed that option. Trac, however, does work.